# Parsing a formatted string into Currency with Power Query (MS Excel)

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm trying to import data from a REST API into MS Excel sheet. Monetary fields comes formatted as "Decimal Number|ISO 3 character currency code", like `123.45|USD`, `678.90|EUR` etc.

How can I parse these values into a Currency (Excel type) column? I tried replacing the pipe character with a space and selecting custom currency formatting types with no avail. I think it expects a currency sign but not a currency code.

Comment: How many currency types in your data? Just USD?

Comment: @DavideBacci not just USD; I sampled the data, there are 9 different currencies at the moment.

Comment: I dont understand the required outcome.  You just want the number? You want the number preceded by a $ or a € character based on the alpha part?

Comment: @horseyride Desired outcome is a number (decimal part before pipe) with a cell formatting of "Currency" (the manual process would be like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuTcW.png)

Comment: Excel does not have a `Currency` data type. What you are seeing is a decimal number formatted to include a currency symbol. If that is what you want, you will need to use VBA since all of the cells will not have the same format. You could do this in PQ replacing the ISO code with the symbol, and returning the string as **Text**, but you can't return numberformatting from PQ to Excel for this type of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fully stand alone query that works. Choose "new query => blank file". Then click the advanced editor, and paste this.

@horseyride used a similar route. I kept the currency type for use.

The `Currency` argument is important, it changes how numbers are converted. Otherwise it uses whatever is the default on the system that runs the query.

You can call your transform function from  "add column" or "Transform column". The main difference is one replaces the original column, the other keeps it.

you can use the function's fallback, or set a culture like this:

```
AsCurrency( row[Text] )
AsCurrency( row[Text], [ Culture = "de-de" ] )
```

```
let
    Json = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjO30LM0qHENDVKK1YlWMjQy1jMxrQkNdlGKjQUA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Text = _t]),
    Source = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Json,{{"Text", type text}}),

    // converts "678.90|EUR" to [ Unit = "EUR", Amount = "678.90" ]
    AsCurrency = ( source as text, optional options as nullable record ) as any => [
        Culture = options[Culture]? ?? "en-us",
        RoundingMode = options[Culture]? ?? null,
        segments = Text.Split( source, "|"),
        return = [
            Unit = segments{1},
            Amount = Currency.From( segments{0}, Culture, RoundingMode )
        ]
    ][return],

    convertFromCurrency = Table.AddColumn( Source, "CoerceCurrency", (row) as record => AsCurrency( row[Text] ), Record.Type ),
    #"Expanded CoerceCurrency" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn( 
        convertFromCurrency, "CoerceCurrency", {"Unit", "Amount"}, {"Unit", "Amount"}),

    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded CoerceCurrency",
        {{"Unit", type text}, {"Amount", Currency.Type}}, "en-us")
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Answer (score 1):

In powerquery you can transform a column to extract everything before the pipe and convert it into a currency value, but the currency character will not persist when loaded back into excel

```
  Split = Table.TransformColumns(#"PriorStepNameHere",{{"ColumnNameHere", each Number.From(Text.BeforeDelimiter(_,"|")), Currency.Type}})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using the PQE transform scripting?
If so, you can use Transform > Extract > Text Before Delimiter to split the cell on the pipe and ignore the currency code field. Cast the remaining field as Currency.

[image: Screen shot of Transform step]

Comment: Thank you; but if possible, I'd like to keep the currency in the same Excel cell (w/ formatting). Your suggestion will make two columns from one field and I unfortunately have many monetary fields in the data.

Comment: If you use the TRANSFORM Ribbon version of Extract, it will edit the cell in place, leaving the results where you want them. Using the ADD COLUMN version is the one that will create multiple columns.

Comment: Did any of these answers work for you? If so please toggle checkmark next to that answer to mark issue solved